# Регулярное выражение Ф.И.О. js

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение "Фамилия Имя Отчество" или "Фамилия Имя", а так же что бы была возможность ввода не только на русском и на английском языке.

Пример ввода в input:
"Иванов Иван Иванович", "Иванов Иван"
"Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich", "Ivanov Ivan"

Не должно быть цифр и спец символов !

Comment: Дайте пример того что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Простите а как вы себе это представляете? ну проставьте проверку на два пробела и между ними чтобы был только текст кириллица и латиница.

Comment: Не проверяйте Фамилии. Из-за таких как вы, я не могу зарегистрироваться под именем "11". Многие сайты не заслуживают даже такого указания моих данных, зато из-за регулярок приходится регистрироваться как "Катигсцнуп Чцтпичуецн"

Comment: только нужно англ. и русские? или например китайские буквы вам то же нужны?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan нет, китайский не нужен

Comment: Ну если только латинские буквы и русские то для них я уже дал ответ

Comment: Жан-Клод не одобрит. ) А вообще, ещё можно глянуть в сторону [dadata](https://dadata.ru/suggestions/#name).

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Голосовать за или против - личное дело каждого. Не вмешивайте в это модераторов. Лично я тоже считаю что вопрос 1) плохо сформулирован; 2) сводится к "сделайте за меня регулярку"; 3) сама идея - проверять фамилии и имена на сайте весьма глупая. Даже в нашей стране найдется уйма людей не попадающих в указанные шаблоны, а если брать еще и латиницу то дело еще сильнее осложняется

Comment: @tutankhamun 1) если плохо сформирован - правка, 2) "сделайте за меня регулярку" - таких вопросов много и такой вопрос можно задать, 3) `проверять фамилии и имена на сайте весьма глупая` ֊ если бы это было глупой идеей то например в `html5` не был бы `<input type="email">`  , И если вопрос сложный то не значит глупый.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan 1) я не знаю в чем именно проблема топикстартера; 2) конечно можно задать и можно получить ответ или минус или полный игнор - тут демократия - я ничего не запрещаю; 3) спорный аргумент

Comment: Что бы были символы из всех языков как то не понятно, если у тебя сайт на определенных языках то дай эти языки, так как то можно сформировать регулярку, но что бы все возможные языки это перебор?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Вы еще не начали считать что вопрос плохо сформулирован? :)

Comment: @tutankhamun ну для этого новичкам надо как то дать советы, а не в игнор кидать.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan отличный совет дал bukkojot. Имя - штука весьма разнообразная. Накладывать ограничения - самый плохой вариант. В большинстве случаев не имеет смысла даже требовать обязательного заполнения. И, как видите, игнора тут не случилось

Comment: Дополните вопрос информацией о том, для чего это вообще вам понадобилось?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как пример , только регулярку доработать что бы не пришлось `if` писать

```
var reg = /([а-яА-яa-zA-z]+\s)+([а-яА-яa-zA-z]+)/ig;
        var str = "Иван Иванов";
        console.log( str.match(reg)[0].length == str.length );
```

Comment: @SP-71, вы вот выбрали ответ, а проверили хоть? Код который сейчас в ответе выдает `не прошла`. Регулярка совершенно бредовая.

Comment: @Visman Ваш ответ ? все работает

Comment: "sdkЛяЛяЛяsjdhf oqoОйОйОйie IDND nd insdff" тоже проходит проверку - это удачное "имя"?

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK, в правках все видно. Реальные ФИО - Румянцев-Задунайский Пётр Александрович и обломс с вашей регуляркой. И главное `не только на русском и на английском языке` :)

Comment: Я ж тоже не всегда успеваю следить за правда "создателя вопроса" :(
(не только на русском и на английском языке)

Answer (score -2):

Вот пример регулярки который проверяет английские и русские символы плюс пробел.

```js
var reg = /^([a-zа-яё\ ]+|\d+)$/ig;
var str = "Иван Иванов";
var str_en = "Petya Petrovich Pupkin";
console.log( str.match(reg) );
console.log( str_en.match(reg) );
```

Обновил регулярку после примечания

```js
var reg = /^([a-zа-яё]+[\s]{0,1}[a-zа-яё]+[\s]{0,1}[a-zа-яё]+)$/ig;

var str = "Иван Иванов";
var str_en = "Petya Petrovich Pupkin";
var str_not_work = "Petya Petrovich Pupkin sfsdfsdf";

console.log( str.match(reg) );
console.log( str_en.match(reg) );
console.log( str_not_work.match(reg) );
```

Comment: не плохо, но по Вашему коду я могу ввести и больше, например, "Petya Petrovich Pupkin Pupkovskiy", а нужно что бы строго было "Petya Petrovich Pupkin"

Comment: @SP-71 И не кто не мешает вам дать свой ответ, но все ровно спасибо за примечание.